# How to create Custom Bottom Tab Bar in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to create a bottom tab bar like given below without using any library like [react-native-material-bottom-navigation](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation) as I don't want any label for my Bottom Tabbars & the library has no option for making label optional. Also it provides animation which looks pretty weird when I used it.

[image: Bottom Tab Bar]

Now I tried implementing a simple tab bar navigation like follows -

#### App.js

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { screen: 1 };
    this.changeScreen = this.changeScreen.bind(this);
  }

  changeScreen() {
    switch (this.state.screen) {
      case 1:
        return <FirstTabScreen />;
      case 2:
        return <SecondTabScreen />;
    }
  }

  changeActiveTab(screen) {
    this.setState({ screen });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          {this.changeScreen()}
        </View>
        <Footer changeActiveTab={this.changeActiveTab} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

#### Footer.js

```
class Footer extends Component {
  render() {
    const { changeActiveTab } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeActiveTab(1)}>
          <Icon name="FirstTabScreen" />
          <Icon name="SecondTabScreen" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
     );
  }
}
```

Its giving an error `this.setState()` is not a function

How to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh bugger !! Got the answer

Missed `this.changeActiveTab = this.changeActiveTab.bind(this);` in the constructor

Gonna start using arrow functions everywhere now